# How to access published .mdf database file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC web application done with Visual Studio 2012 (C#).

I use database in my `App_Data` folder.

Finally, I publish my web application in FTP.

But a problem, how can I alter and add new tables in the future.

There is no SQL Server installation on my IIS Server.

Comment: How does your spplication access the database if there's no sql server running on the web server?

Comment: no need to have sql server in IIS server, do you have sql server in your network?

Comment: PMF I mean there no Sql Server Management console in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install express version of SQL on the server if possible. Or else, you can use your local installation to connect to MDF file on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. Sorry, there is some problem to 
install the Sql in the IIS Server. I mean i want to add a column in my table. But i didn't attach the published .mdf file. Can i use any other tool to connect the .mdf file

Comment: You do not install SQL on IIS. Also, you can use your local SSMS installation to access the MDF file.

Comment: I create this mdf file using my visual studio 2012. Last day i download the .mdf file from the FTP and connect the .mdf file to my
sql server 2008. I get a error about version problem. Sql Server 2012 is required for this ?